# Java Code inside JSP: How to put double quotes

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Our legacy code use Java directly inside JSP. I cannot use EL. I got a problem here:

```
<jbo:DataSource id="dsyn" appid="AM_Quebec" viewobject="YesnoView1" 
                whereclause='<%="yesno.yn_lang="+locale%>'>
```

For the whereclause, what I really want is like this:

```
String yesno_wc = "yesno.yn_lang='" + locale + "'";
```

Anybody knows how to put the yesno_wc in the where clause? Thanks

Comment: did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can escape double quotes with a backslash.

I might first store that value, here is an example JSP storing the value in a scriptlet, then using a tag with a JSP expression as the value.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
where
<% String withQuotes = " 'column'='\"value\"' "; %>
<c:out value="<%= withQuotes %>"/>
```

which produces

```
where 'column'='"value"'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can escape double quotes with a backslash.

I might first store that value, here is an example JSP storing the value in a scriptlet, then using a tag with a JSP expression as the value.