# How to handle special characters in DB mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I am using MySQL Server Management Studio, Jsp, Java, Js. 
I have issue with displaying correctly the data I get from DB.

I have store some text with open and close quotation, and it does not display correctly on my jsp page. Eg:

```
A STUDY OF THE CASE OF BENJAMIN BUTTON "BY ARTHUR C CLARKE"

Displayed as :
A STUDY OF THE CASE OF BENJAMIN BUTTON  ARTHUR C 
"BY CLARKE"
```

I wonder do I need to wrap the query result with something when I get from the DB or do I need to insert into DB like (\"), but below does not work, also I notice single quotation mark(') also have similar issue :

```
A STUDY OF THE CASE OF BENJAMIN BUTTON \"BY ARTHUR C CLARKE\"
```

Comment: If you really inserted that literal string, then you should be seeing it in your JSP page.  What happens when you directly run a select against the table in MySQL?  Do you see the correct title string?

Answer (score 0):

could you include some parts of your code please?
it would be hard to find out what's the problem just by description.
however if it was me i would try the following solutions:

1-like Tim Biegeleisen said, check if you see the correct string.

2-i know it might sound weird but once i had the same problem and i converted the string to byte and then add that to db in a temporary table just to see if there was any problem with any character in my string.(I was surprised that it worked for me and found the problem :)  )

3- check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145328/java-code-inside-jsp-how-to-put-double-quotes) you might get the answer.